# Visualforce page insert lead and redirect to url

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm very new to coding and trying to create a visualforce page form that will be published to external entities to get more leads, after keying in information required, hit save and the page will redirect to our homepage which is outside of SF.
I have the code as below when ever I submit the form there is error happen:

> Attempt to de-reference a null object
>
> Error is in expression '{!savelead}' in component  in page driver_capture: Class.redirectPg.savelead: line 17, column 1

VF Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" standardController="Lead" extensions="redirectPg" title="Register Form">

<apex:form id="frm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Thông tin" id="pg_blk">
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:outputLabel >Last Name: </apex:outputLabel></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:inputField id="lastName" value="{!lead.LastName}" required="true"/></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:outputLabel >First Name: </apex:outputLabel></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:inputField id="firstName" value="{!lead.FirstName}" required="true"/></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:outputLabel >Phone*: </apex:outputLabel></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:inputField id="MobilePhone" value="{!lead.MobilePhone}" required="true"/></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:inputHidden id="record_type" value="{!lead.RecordTypeId}"/>
    <script>
        var inputRecordTypeEle = document.getElementById("{!$Component.frm.pg_blk.block1.record_type}");
            if (inputRecordTypeEle != null) {
                 inputRecordTypeEle.value='0121s0000004J0mAAE';
                    }
        </script>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!savelead}" value="Signup Now!"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class redirectPg {
Public redirectPg(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

}

Lead lead;

Public PageReference savelead(){
    insert lead;
    PageReference reRend = new PageReference('https://abc.xyz/');
    reRend.setRedirect(true);
    return reRend;
}}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the Lead record from the `ApexPages.StandardController` parameter/ to the variable:

```
Public redirectPg(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    lead = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
}
```

Otherwise, this variable is null, thus causing the `NullPointerException` you're getting.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works with abit modification as below

Public redirectPg(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    lead = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
}

Comment: @Tuyến Good point. I'd forgotten a cast is necessary. I'll update the answer to reflect that.